# Getting ORA-00904 invalid identifier executing multi table insert query

Tags: insert, oracle10g

I'm just trying 'multi table insert'. Below is my insert query. I'm trying to insert values from employees table to table t1,t2 and t3. After executing the query i'm getting an error.

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEES"."LAST_NAME": invalid identifier
```

The column last_name is exist in employees table. But why i'm getting this error.

```
insert all
into t1(id,l_name) values(employees.employee_id,employees.last_name)
into t2(id,l_name) values(employees.employee_id,employees.last_name)
into t3(id,l_name) values(employees.employee_id,employees.last_name)
select * from employees;
/
```

I've also tried replacing table name and column name to upper case. Still facing the same error. I'm using Oracle 10g.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After removing the reference table name employees from column name its working.

Answer:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO t1(id, l_name) VALUES (employee_id, last_name)
INTO t2(id, l_name) VALUES (employee_id, last_name)
INTO t3(id, l_name) VALUES (employee_id, last_name)
SELECT * FROM employees;
```